# echo "c:\tmp\" > //$(repoServer)/c/tmp/$(TestCaseID)/execute.bat(How to print \t in shell script )

Tags: shell

I want to echo below thing

```
echo "c:\tmp\$(TestCaseID)\$(repoZipExtractedName)\windows_downloader.bat -
    configFile c:\tmp\$(TestCaseID)/$(OfflineDownloader_FileName)" > //$(repoServer)/c/tmp/$(TestCas  eID)/execute.bat
```

I am getting below out put
    c:      mp\DRBLG-55573\All-OS-Patch-Downloaders-windows-build-
        8.9.01\windows_downloader.bat -configFile c: mp\DRBLG-55573/sample-
        windows-downloader-config.xml

it is considering **"\t" in \tmp as is considered  tab** can any one help me how to deal with this.

I am Using Shell. Running the command on Windows using Cygwin

Comment: Which shell language, exactly? We have different tags for PowerShell, cmd.exe, etc. (`shell` is often used for POSIX sh, a standard on UNIX; this clearly isn't that).

Comment: I am Using Shell. Running the command on Windows using Cygwin

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution for same. Adding **-E** worked for me

```
echo -E '\tmp\\$(TestCaseID)\\$(repoZipExtractedName)\\windows_downloader.bat' -configFile '$(fileDir)\\$(TestCaseID)\\$(OfflineDownloader_FileName)' > //$(repoServer)/c/tmp/$(TestCaseID)/execute.bat
```

for Echo related Quires refer below link

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo

Comment: `$()` doesn't make sense here -- you're **running a command** called `TestCaseID`? Or is this really makefile syntax, and not shell syntax? (In a POSIX-style shell, it would be `${TestCaseID}` to substitute a variable by that name, not `$(TestCaseID)`, which runs a command and substitutes its output).

Comment: Thanks Charles for Investing your time. TestCaseID is a variable which I have initialized in Previous steps I didnt bring it into this context.I am writing  this  piece of code for our internal tool which works with most shell(with some exception) But any way it worked Thanks

Comment: `$(TestCaseID)` absolutely does not expand variable `TestCaseID` in any standard-compliant POSIX shell. If it's doing that for you, your environment is clearly not a POSIX-compliant shell.